# wordpress multisite concerns

Tags: wordpress, multisite

The issues I'm facing now on deploying wordpress multisite:

1. when enabling the parent wordpress (eg. http://www.example.com/multisiteparent/ as Site A) to become multisite, do i also
   need to enalbe multisite network setup in each one of the children
   site in wp-config.php again? (i'm wondering if i do not enable network in children site
   (eg. http://www.example.com/multisiteparent/childsite/ as Site B) when i click into dashboard of the child site wp-admin, there would be no network panel(multisite wp-admin feature) to navigate back to parent site wp dashboard. the official documentation seems like didn't mention this setting.
2. which procedure is regarded better when i want to migrate two independent wp sites (site A & site B) into multisite (A as parent, B as sub-site).
   **option1:**    set up a blank wordpress multisite structure then migrate wp files and sqls(A & B)     to the tables created by clean wordpress with diff wp_ and wp_2_ table prefixes. this might have to do string replacement in sql before migration. 
   **option2:**    start from enalbing site A to become multisite, then create a blank site sub directory and migrate site B into the created folder ( files and sql replacement)
3. Is there any existing wordpress multisite demos online that worked
   very well on data sharing?  how widely is it used as a solution.
4. As i found by enabling multisite, auto created prefix such as
   wp_2_options wp_2_posts.... etc inside the  same database. will this cause
   imcompatibilites to plugins of the wordpress?
5. Alternative solutions other than activating multisite to share
   tables between different wordpress sites of diff domain?

Thank u for the suggestions.

Reference:

- https://wordpress.org/support/article/multisite-network-administration/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite
- https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/the-complete-guide-to-creating-a-wordpress-multisite-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of questions!  :-)

1. You only do this once.  There's only one wp.config for the entire multisite installation, not one for each child site.
2. option 1 should work fine.  easiest way (i do this all the time) is to use any text editor on the sql file and replace wp_ with wp_1_ or wp_2_ or whatever.  then copy over your plugins and themes to the parent folder (you don't have separate folders for each).  then use a plugin like [Go Live Update URLS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/) to change all of your urls for your media attachments (multisite has a different folder hierarchy for uploads).
3. no idea what you're asking here.
4. a few plugins will not work for multisite, but most will.  it depends on the plugin.
5. using multisite is the easiest.  you could always build something completely custom (using your own database connections to open up whatever shared tables you want) but that's a lot of work.

Comment: thanks for your useful suggestions, i've been able to set up multisite and do migrations etc, still one question left abt post syn of multisite troubles me, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730466/wordpress-multisite-syncronize-custom-post-type-solution