# WordPress Multisite redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

I have a question about WordPress multisite. Currently have 2 sites in sub-directory mode. Everything works fine until I wanted to access the WordPress Multisite Network tab which ends up with "*ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*". We have both HTTPS and HTTP sites working, yet currently not forcing redirect.

Our `.htacces` looks like:

```
    # START XML RPC BLOCKING
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
# FINISH XML RPC BLOCKING

#
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.oursite.cz/$1 [R,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule wp-content/thesis/skins/(.*)/css.css wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and Our `wp-config.php` is like this:

```
/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
//define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);


/* Multisite */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.oursite.cz');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

So far we have tried following, but nothing helped:

1. [wordpress multisite concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034243/wordpress-multisite-concerns)
2. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-multisite-too-many-redirects-on-wp-admin/

Currently running WordPress Version 4.8.2, but the WordPress has been updated few times and the Multisite was created quite a while ago (still with the same problem). Server is Apache 2.2.31 and PHP 5.4.44.

We would be really grateful if you could provide any tips.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudflare, from SSL/TLS tab of your Cloudflare account, select Full encryption. It will solve the issue.

[image: SSL TO FULL]

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved the site recently then check in your database for references to the old domain and update to the new domain. This includes moving from http to https.

You could also try updating permalinks in WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Save

Answer (score 0):

I add the same problem using lightsail on AWS and Wordpress multisite with subdomain.

I solved it doing this:

1. Create a .htaccess file and paste content
   nano /opt/bitnami/wordpress/.htaccess

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

2. Change the domain with:
   *sudo /opt/bitnami/configure_app_domain --domain your-domain.com*